# Cant change advanced blogs title PHPfox v4

Tags: blogs, phpfox

Iv tried everything but it just wont let me change it iv uninstalled it and installed but still no luck has anyone else had this problem?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around you need to delete it from you menu then re add it and name it whatever you want and save all done YAY!!